# Import-Spweb changing the user id if the user does not exist in the organization

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I tried to restore a list (which has versionsing enabled) using following command mentioned below:

```
Import-SPWeb http://example.com/projects/myList -path "E:\backups\myList\myList.cmp" -IncludeUserSecurity -UpdateVersions overwrite
```

The list was restored, however the users that did not exist in the organization any longer were replaced with the user who performed the restore. Shouldn't the versioning flag address this? Has anyone else faced this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, so when the import happens it has to query AD to put that user back into the user information list.  When someone doesn't exist it can't add the person so instead it picks the person doing the import which it knows exists.  Unfortunately, this is the case with import/export.  If you need to keep the data more intact, a full site collection backup/restore does not have these types of issues.